# Can I add the Model function property in the API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Can I add the Model function property in the API?

I have a Model:

```
class PhysicalServer(models.Model):
    name = name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    trade_record = models.ForeignKey(to=TradeRecord, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_applied(self):
        if self.trade_record == None:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

my `PhysicalServerListAPIView` of it:

```
class PhysicalServerListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PhysicalServerListSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = PhysicalServer.objects.all()
```

the `PhysicalServerListSerializer`:

```
class PhysicalServerListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PhysicalServer
        fields = "__all__"
```

I have a requirement, how can I add the `is_applied` to the list API?

I mean, if I access the ListAPI, the results data will be like:

```
{
  name: xxx,
  trade_record: xxx
},
...
```

How can I add this?

```
{
  name: xxx,
  trade_record: xxx
  is_applied: xxx
},
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the field description to the serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class PhysicalServerListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    is_applied = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PhysicalServer
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `SerializerMethodField` is what are you looking for.

Try this way.

```
class PhysicalServerListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    is_applied = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = PhysicalServer
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_is_applied(self, obj):
        return self.trade_record is not None:
```

For more info: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield